# Cannot find module '@amcharts/amcharts4/timeline' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, amcharts4

I am trying to add Amchart Timeline Graph in my angular project

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
import * as am4plugins_timeline from "@amcharts/amcharts4/timeline"; // <-------------
import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";
```

I am getting error to import am4plugins_timeline!
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
import * as am4plugins_timeline from "@amcharts/amcharts4/plugins/timeline";
```

Comment: Thank you @sun !

Comment: But now I am getting this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: am4internal_webpackJsonp is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/plugins/timeline.js